# Export the contour lines of the relief from OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, export, contour, api

My goal is to display the contour lines of the relief in Google Earth.

So, I would like to export from OpenStreetMap the contour lines of the relief of a region.
My goal is to download the data as a kml, to load them into Google Map.

I was hoping a query like that to work in [OverPass](https://overpass-turbo.eu/):

```
node
  ["contour"="elevation"]
  (42,1,43,1.5);
out body;
```

It does not. I could not find a more appropriate tag. According to [OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags), it does not exist.

Is there any other way?

Comment: I don't think OSM includes contours (kind of tricky for volunteer surveyors to add) - https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features

Comment: see the workflow, data source etc: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Contour_relief_maps_using_mapnik

Comment: Too bad. But thank you :) As I am still trying to get the contour lines of a small region as a kml. Whatever the source. Should I open a new question or edit this one?

Answer (score 2):

Contour lines in OSM based maps are generated from other source data. It would make no sense to store contour lines into the OSM database because they would require much more space than the rest of the data. Also contour lines are derived from digital elevation model data and not created or edited by OSM contributors.

See the documentation of the map that you are using about the sources. For example OpenCycleMap creates the contour lines from SRTM data https://www.opencyclemap.org/docs/

> Credits Height Data is from NASA’s SRTM and is available in the public
> domain.

If the developers of the map project are kind enough they might be willing to share their contour lines or at least the work flow of creating contours from DEM data.